# Flutter clean take more time

Tags: ios, flutter

When I run " Flutter clean" this take many time to execute and i have no response.
I wait several time but no response. It's look like the problem is ios.

```
flutter clean -v
[ +101 ms] executing: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
[  +22 ms] Exit code 1 from: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
[        ] sysctl: unknown oid 'hw.optional.arm64'
[   +5 ms] executing: [/Users/baayfalltakkjokk/development/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +23 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 18116933e77adc82f80866c928266a5b4f1ed645
[        ] executing: [/Users/baayfalltakkjokk/development/flutter/] git tag --points-at 18116933e77adc82f80866c928266a5b4f1ed645
[  +84 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at 18116933e77adc82f80866c928266a5b4f1ed645
....
[  +76 ms] executing: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
[   +6 ms] Exit code 1 from: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
[        ] sysctl: unknown oid 'hw.optional.arm64'
[        ] executing: xcrun xcodebuild -version
[ +218 ms] Exit code 0 from: xcrun xcodebuild -version
[        ] Xcode 13.2.1
           Build version 13C100
[   +5 ms] Cleaning Xcode workspace...
[   +2 ms] executing: [/Users/baayfalltakkjokk/Documents/PROJETS/projetsFlutter/my_project/ios/] xcrun xcodebuild -list
```

Comment: What is the version of flutter? flutter --version

Comment: Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-x64, locale fr-SN)
    • Flutter version 2.5.3 at /Users/baayfalltakkjokk/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18116933e7 (10 weeks ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
    • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
    • Dart version 2.14.4

Comment: I think problem with your SDK please run flutter upgrade or re set up your SDK.

Comment: Also, it may be security permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Remove all unused dependencies
>
> ```
> flutter run -d web-server
> ```